# Check if :make fails

Tags: key-bindings, external-command, filetype-tex, makeprg

I just setup this mapping for my latex development:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <LocalLeader>o :make %:r.pdf <Bar> !open %:r.pdf<CR><CR><CR>
```

But I wondered about checking if `:make` fails before running `!open`, so that I don't open an old version for some reason.

I know if it were `:!make`, I could check `v:shellerror`; however, I cannot find any documentation on `:make` errors outside of what's put in the quickfix list.

Comment: Vim seems to set `v:shell_error` for `:make`. Is this question about Neovim specifically?

Comment: You just got *Yahtzee!* on your reputation! 

Comment: @Matt The issue is with the `| tee` in `'shellpipe'`, it basically always returns 0 and masks the error return code of the `make` program... I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: @Matt no, I don’t use neovim at the moment

Answer (score 4):

Vim *will* set `v:shell_error` with a `:make` invocation, same as it does for other ways it executes external commands using the shell.

The most likely reason why you're not seeing the error code of the `make` execution in `v:shell_error` (and always seeing it return 0) is that on Unix platforms and  most common shells Vim defaults to piping the output of execution of `'makeprg'` through the `tee` program, in order to have it both displayed on the terminal and saved to a file which gets loaded into the quickfix buffer.

This is controlled by the [`'shellpipe'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shellpipe%27) option, which defaults to `2>&1| tee` on most Unix platforms.

You can override this behavior (but not get to see the output of your `'makeprg'` in the terminal) by overriding it not to include a pipe to `tee`. For example:

```
:set shellpipe=>%s\ 2>&1
```

Then after running `:make` you'll get `v:shell_error` to store the error return of the external command.

If you're using bash as your shell and your `'makeprg'` is a single program (rather than a pipeline), you can also use the following to run it through `tee` and still capture the exit code of the `'makeprg'`:

```
:let &shellpipe = ' 2>&1| tee %s; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}'
```

Comment: Hm this is interesting. Certainly makes it more complicated! May not be worth it. But you’ve certainly answered the question

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to try to parse Quickfix List itself. For example,

```
" check if the last line contains "Error" or "Stop"
function! QfError() abort
    return getqflist()[-1].text =~# 'Error\|Stop'
endfunction
```

Of course, such stuff is very fragile, as it relies on `&makeprg` output having a known format.